# I am trying to write a recursive programme in python but I can't seem grasp the logic

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a python programme that collects keys from a dictionary and display its value. I am using a get_close_match from difflib library and I need to create a recursion a displays the next value in the dictionary after entering "n" for no. There is the working code:

```
import json
import difflib
from difflib import get_close_matches

data = json.load(open("data.json"))
data_keys = data.keys()

word=input("Enter word to be defined here:\n")

if word.capitalize() in data:
    word=word.capitalize()
elif word.upper() in data:
    word=word.upper()
else:
    word=word.lower()

word=str(word)

def meaning():
    if word in data:
        for i in data[word]:
            print(i+"\n")
    elif len(get_close_matches(word,data_keys)) > 0:
        YorN = input("Do you mean %s ? \nIf it is enter :(y) else enter: (n) \n" % get_close_matches(word,data_keys)[0])
        if YorN in {"y","yes","Y","(y)","(Y)"}:
            for i in data[str(get_close_matches(word,data_keys)[0])]:
                print(i+"\n")
        elif YorN in {"n","no","N","(n)","(N)"}:
            YorN1 = input("Do you mean %s ? \nIf it is enter :(y) else enter: (n) \n" % get_close_matches(word,data_keys)[1])
            if YorN1 in {"y","yes","Y","(y)","(Y)"}:
                for i in data[str(get_close_matches(word,data_keys)[1])]:
                    print(i+"\n")
            elif YorN1 in {"n","no","N","(n)","(N)"}:
                YorN2 = input("Do you mean %s ? \nIf it is enter :(y) else enter: (n) \n" % get_close_matches(word,data_keys)[2])
                if YorN2 in {"y","yes","Y","(y)","(Y)"}:
                    for i in data[str(get_close_matches(word,data_keys)[2])]:
                        print(i+"\n")
                else: print("Sorry couldn't find this word, ensure the spelling is correct!")
        else : print("Sorry couldn't find this word, ensure the spelling is correct!")
    else : print("Sorry couldn't find this word, ensure the spelling is correct!")

meaning()
```

I am hoping I can have a recursive code that is more efficient without having to repeat the same line of code. To all the py gurus kindly take it easy on me I'm a newbie.

Comment: It looks like some lists/strings you typed out could just be variables. I'm not sure what recursion you are wanting, it looks fine to me. You might get more responses on the codereview stack :) codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This functionality is not a problem solved with recursion.  Make a simple `for` loop to iterate over the matches and break out when the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

```
def nextClosestMatch(attempt):
    YorN = input("Do you mean %s ? \nIf it is enter :(y) else enter: (n) \n" %
             get_close_matches(word, data_keys)[attempt])
    if YorN in {"y", "yes", "Y", "(y)", "(Y)"}:
        for i in data[str(get_close_matches(word, data_keys)[attempt])]:
            print(i+"\n")
    elif YorN in {"n", "no", "N", "(n)", "(N)"}:
        nextClosestMatch(attempt+1)
    else:
        print("Sorry couldn't find this word, ensure the spelling is correct!")

def meaning():
    if word in data:
        for i in data[word]:
            print(i+"\n")
    elif len(get_close_matches(word, data_keys)) > 0:
        nextClosestMatch(0)
```

I think this is what you are looking for, upon not finding the correct item, it will call itself looking for the next closest match

Comment: yay!!! It solved the recursive problem, but a new problem was born: IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: Is it possible to check the amount of times the function can run against the number of items in the list: (get_close_matches(word, data_keys)) and stop at the last item on the list. Thank though @Kyle DePace, you gave me a better understanding of recursion.